# Installing Octave with Brew in Lion

Tags: macos, error, homebrew

my first question on AskDifferent! (let me know if I'm doing it wrong.) Anyway, I'm trying to install octave using brew and am getting the following error but unsure how to proceed:

>  ~/ brew install octave
>   ==> Installing octave dependency: cmake
>   ==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/cmake-2.8.7
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> Error: SHA1 mismatch
>   Expected: f218ed64ce6e7a5d3670acdd6a18e5ed95421d1f
>   Got: 3a57f6f44186e0dba34ef8b8fb4a9047e9e5d8a3
>   Archive: /Users/Billy/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake-2.8.7.bottle.tar.gz
>   (To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
>
>  ~/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
B

Comment: Tried to tag with octave but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemingly have a bad download in the cache. Do this:

```
rm /Users/Billy/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cmake-2.8.7.bottle.tar.gz
```

And then try again. Make sure you're up-to-date first: `brew update`.

Comment: I actually already tried that before I posted and just ended up with the same error ... Thanks though edit: missed your note to brew update, had completely overlooked that ... trying again. will get back if it succeeds.

Comment: ah the sweet taste of success. hat tip to you sir.

Comment: I think one of our maintainers changed the file keeping its filename the same. So this error can occur. I apologise.